# Understanding debugger output in VSCode

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug some node-application but I don't know how to interprete the variables section. As shown in the screenshot, the VSCode shows a lot of "members" as childs under the variable 'cf' which seems to be a function. But I'm confused than, because

1. Does that mean, that the childs are variables within the functions definition
2. What is the meaning of the [[]] Brackets?
3. What is the meaning of the __ __ Underscores?

[image]

Comment: Things inside `[[ ... ]]` all come from ECMAScript's internals.  Search [the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html) for "BoundArgs", for example.

Comment: As for `cf`, search the same spec for "CF is a constructor".  This is found in `4.2.1 Objects`

Comment: I would submit an answer, but I'm having trouble coming up with a demo that contains `cf`.  My current demo contains `[[BoundArgs]]`, `[[BoundThis]]`, and `[[TargetFunction]]`.  I can submit this as an answer, but I feel its incomplete without `cf`.

Comment: I would be appreciate if you would post your answer. Everything could be helpful and if neccessary you can edit your answer later.